# Best metrics on exotic R^4

Tags: riemannian-geometry, differential-topology

What is known about the existence of complete metrics with good properties (e.g., Einstein, constant scalar curvature, etc...) on exotic ${\bf R}^4$s?  Note, that some exotic ${\bf R}^4$s have **non-complete** Kähler-Einstein metrics being open subsets of ${\bf C}P^2$.

One could also ask the much simpler question if there are any more or less explicitly constructed complete metrics on some exotic ${\bf R}^4$s, maybe with bounded curvature or satisfying some other decent condition?

There are some obvious obstructions to good metrics on exotic ${\bf R}^4$s arising from Hopf-Rinow, Cheeger-Gromoll splitting, etc.  What is known about "non-obvious" obstructions?

Comment: It is theorem of Robert E Greene that every smooth manifold admits complete riemannian metrics with bounded geometry i.e the curvature and all its covariant derivatives are bounded and the injectivity radius is bounded below by a positive constant .

Comment: Maybe it is worth noting that every (paracompact) manifold of dimension $n \geq 3$ admits a complete metric of scalar curvature -1.  This was proved by Aubin (in the compact case) and Bland-Kalka, and reproved (among other things) by Lohkamp in http://www.jstor.org/stable/10.2307/2118620.

Comment: This is an old question, but could someone comment on the meaning of "obvious constructions" arising from Comparison Geometry? How does Geodesic completeness give any control over the exotic structure?